# How to set status codes such as 401 and 403?

Tags: php, http

Setting a 404 in WordPress can be done quite easily using the `set_404()` method of `WP_Query` and the `status_header()` function. Here's an example taken from `WP::handle_404()`:

```
$wp_query->set_404();
status_header( 404 );
nocache_headers();
```

If I wanted my tag archive to be accessible to authenticated users only, setting a 404 page for non-authenticated users wouldn't make sense because the resource does exist, it's just not available to logged-out users.

**My question**

How would I set a 401 in WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you would in any other PHP program:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
exit;
```

WordPress has special handling for 404 because there's a 404 template. Usually if something happens such as a 401, there is no special template, but you can make use of `wp_die` which will show a message in a simple UI

```
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized");
wp_die( 'forbidden' );
```

This will show the message in a white rectangle with rounded edges and sans-serif text on a gray background, then call `exit`/`die`